# Different Font versions of Tahoma on Win7/10?

Tags: java, windows, fonts

I have a Win7(64bit) machine that renders a text in a Java application with squares instead of ligature-ff (Unicode FB00) and ligature-ffi (Unicode FB03) if using Tahoma as a font. The same application renders the same chars perfectly in Tahoma under Win10.

Using charmap i discovered that there is indeed no such char in Tahoma (Win7), while it exists on Win10-Tahoma.

BUT Word, and an older version of my app (using Java 8 instead of 11) on Win7 at least use the ligatures from other fonts instead (Word:Cambria Math, OldApp:ArialUnicodeMS), which is why it never stood out to me before.

Windows7 has Tahoma 5.22, while Win10 has Tahoma 6.9 - i didn't know those were held at different versions (why?).

Anybody up to explaining the different behaviours in replacing unknown chars (get them from another font vs. render them as squares)? Microsoft has a systemwide Fallback font, but as IE, Word and N++ all handle the rendering of Tahoma + ligature-ff differently, that does not seem to do much.

Comment: As far as I know, Microsoft has never released an updated version of a font for an older operating system;  the only way to get such font fixes has been to upgrade Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I run into a same problem recently. Font character sets are different in different OS versions, and it isn't marked anywhere! Spent days fighting to get a simple character to appear from font that it should contain by every source I found. (G with a caron. Courier New shipped with Win 10 has it, but Courier New in XP doesn't.)

How hard it is to just add version number to font files?? To figure it out, just trust character map. It shows all the characters font has.

When you know this, it's easy fix. Get on computer that has the version of font with char you need. Go to WINDOWS\FONTS, and copy paste the font file you need to that other computer.

You can update all the fonts in the computer same way, if you want.